# Excel: random groupmaking

Tags: excel, random

Situation:

120 people have to choose 3 choices from a list of 10.

i need to pick at random 2 from their choices (per person) and divide them (the 120 people) in 12 groups.

the 12 groups are: the list of 10 + 2 doubles from the list of 10 who were chosen the most.

Maximum size of a group is 20.

I have found this formula to chose 1 random choice out of 3 but am stuck for the next step:

=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA($A$2:$A$4)),1)

where the choices of the first person are situated in A2, A3 and A4

Any ideas?

example data:

list of 10 choices:
choice1
choice2
...
choice10

list of 120 users:
user1
user2
...
user120

list of 12 groups:
groupchoice1
groupchoice2
...
groupchoice10
groupchoicewhatevergetspickedthemost
groepchoicewhatevergetspickedthesecondmost

user1 chose choice4, choice6 and choice10

user2 chose choice1, choice4, choice7

user3 chose choice5, choice6, choice7

...

user120 chose choice3, choice4, choice9

=> i need to randomly pick 2 from the 3 choices from each user and place that user in those 2 groups. Fill the groups until 20.

Comment: It is hard to understand your problem. Maybe you can add en example?

Comment: added some example data.

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to do -- but why are you trying to do it *randomly*? That makes it much harder to satisfy the constraint of 20 in each group (with each person in 2 different groups). If you drop the randomness requirement it can be set up as an integer programming problem which can be tackled by the solver. Otherwise, VBA would probably be needed. Simple spreadsheet formulas are unlikely to be adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Setup the file... :

```
column A = user1 user2 ... user120. [starting at A1]
column B,C,D = "choice1 choice2 choice3"
column G,H = "pick 2 from the 3 choices"

column F is used for G & H determination.
```

As for the values

```
A1 = user1
A2 = user2 ...
```

and the formulas :

```
B1 ---> =RANDBETWEEN(1,10)
C1 ---> =INDEX(IF(B1=1,{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},IF(B1=2,{1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},IF(B1=3,{1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},IF(B1=4,{1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10},IF(B1=5,{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10},IF(B1=6,{1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10},IF(B1=7,{1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10},IF(B1=8,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10},IF(B1=9,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10},IF(B1=10,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},"ERROR")))))))))),RANDBETWEEN(1,9))
D1 ---> =INDEX(IF(OR(AND(B1=1,C1=2),AND(B1=2,C1=1)),{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=1,C1=3),AND(B1=3,C1=1)),{2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=1,C1=4),AND(B1=4,C1=1)),{2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=1,C1=5),AND(B1=5,C1=1)),{2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=1,C1=6),AND(B1=6,C1=1)),{2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=1,C1=7),AND(B1=7,C1=1)),{2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=1,C1=8),AND(B1=8,C1=1)),{2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=1,C1=9),AND(B1=9,C1=1)),{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=1,C1=10),AND(B1=10,C1=1)),{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},IF(OR(AND(B1=2,C1=3),AND(B1=3,C1=2)),{1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=2,C1=4),AND(B1=4,C1=2)),{1,3,5,6,7,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=2,C1=5),AND(B1=5,C1=2)),{1,3,4,6,7,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=2,C1=6),AND(B1=6,C1=2)),{1,3,4,5,7,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=2,C1=7),AND(B1=7,C1=2)),{1,3,4,5,6,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=2,C1=8),AND(B1=8,C1=2)),{1,3,4,5,6,7,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=2,C1=9),AND(B1=9,C1=2)),{1,3,4,5,6,7,8,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=2,C1=10),AND(B1=10,C1=2)),{1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},IF(OR(AND(B1=3,C1=4),AND(B1=4,C1=3)),{1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=3,C1=5),AND(B1=5,C1=3)),{1,2,4,6,7,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=3,C1=6),AND(B1=6,C1=3)),{1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=3,C1=7),AND(B1=7,C1=3)),{1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=3,C1=8),AND(B1=8,C1=3)),{1,2,4,5,6,7,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=3,C1=9),AND(B1=9,C1=3)),{1,2,4,5,6,7,8,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=3,C1=10),AND(B1=10,C1=3)),{1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9},IF(OR(AND(B1=4,C1=5),AND(B1=5,C1=4)),{1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=4,C1=6),AND(B1=6,C1=4)),{1,2,3,5,7,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=4,C1=7),AND(B1=7,C1=4)),{1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=4,C1=8),AND(B1=8,C1=4)),{1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=4,C1=9),AND(B1=9,C1=4)),{1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=4,C1=10),AND(B1=10,C1=4)),{1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9},IF(OR(AND(B1=5,C1=6),AND(B1=6,C1=5)),{1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=5,C1=7),AND(B1=7,C1=5)),{1,2,3,4,6,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=5,C1=8),AND(B1=8,C1=5)),{1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=5,C1=9),AND(B1=9,C1=5)),{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=5,C1=10),AND(B1=10,C1=5)),{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9},IF(OR(AND(B1=6,C1=7),AND(B1=7,C1=6)),{1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=6,C1=8),AND(B1=8,C1=6)),{1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=6,C1=9),AND(B1=9,C1=6)),{1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=6,C1=10),AND(B1=10,C1=6)),{1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9},IF(OR(AND(B1=7,C1=8),AND(B1=8,C1=7)),{1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=7,C1=9),AND(B1=9,C1=7)),{1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=7,C1=10),AND(B1=10,C1=7)),{1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9},IF(OR(AND(B1=8,C1=9),AND(B1=9,C1=8)),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10},IF(OR(AND(B1=8,C1=10),AND(B1=10,C1=8)),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9},IF(OR(AND(B1=9,C1=10),AND(B1=10,C1=9)),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},"error"))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))),RANDBETWEEN(1,8))
F1 ---> =RANDBETWEEN(1,3)
G1 ---> =IF(F1=1,C1,B1)
H1 ---> =IF(F1<>3,D1,C1)
```

Hope this helps.. (: